# What am I not understating about using Maps in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react however I have done this same(ish) thing multiple times, however, this time it is just not working - I am assuming there is something I am fundamentaily not understanding. Please help!

I have a good old table:

```
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <TableRowUser key={1} />
                <TableRowUser key={2} />
                <TableRowUser key={3} />              
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

And a row:

```
import React from 'react';

const TableRowUser = () => {
  return <tr>
      <td>TEST</td>
      <td>TEST</td>
  </tr>;
};

export default TableRowUser;
```

This works just as expected.

However, when I change from hard code to using a map - nothing is rendered:

```
...
            <tbody>
                {users.map(user => {
                    console.log(user.name);
                    <TableRowUser key={user.id} />
                })}
            </tbody>
...
```

I should note - my data is fine as this console log prints correctly.
Just no TableRowUser is returned.

This appears trivial - What am I missing?

Comment: maybe show your TableRowUser function/class?

Comment: actually, the problem is you don't return the value from the function

Comment: THANKYOU! I knew it was something trivial that I couldn't see. Appreciate your time. Time to go and review JS I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are running into is how arrow functions work.

You can do:

`() =>  value`

for a quick way to return a value, but if you are putting a body on the code, you need to use the `return` keyword

`() => { return value }`

Thus, your code should be:

```
<tbody>
            {users.map(user => {
                console.log(user.name);
                return <TableRowUser key={user.id} />
            })}
        </tbody>
```

or just

```
<tbody>
            {users.map(user => <TableRowUser key={user.id} />)}
</tbody>
```